# how to use bootstrap 4 container inside a container-fluid, How to text always stay inside a container

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

how to use bootstrap 4 container inside a container-fluid[how to design it to text at the blue part always takes inside a container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQVfy.png)

Comment: please show us what you have tried. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just like this :)

https://jsfiddle.net/7pd5xn6h/2/

```css
.container-fluid-bg {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container-bg {
  background-color: green;
  min-height:300px;
}

.row-bg {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col-bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-bg">
  <div class="container container-bg">
    <div class="row row-bg">
 
      <div class="col-7 offset-1 col-bg">
        Hello
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-bg">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```